Is the includes function for strings in javascript impacted by punctuation?
I am trying to figure out a bug where I am looking for a subset of text in an array of iconNames. My filter looks like this:
name = isName ? images[iconNames.filter(icon => icon.includes(string))[0]] : ""

this works for all the other strings like "Surfing" or "Sports", and have icon names SurfingIcon or SportsIcon. My issue is with the string "Who has time for hobbies?" which has an icon name WhoHasTimeForHobbiesIcon. I know includes is supposed to grab subset strings and I feel like this qualifies. I am wondering if the ? is impacting this or if there is something else going on.
I could probably change the way this is filtered, but i just wound up manually setting it for the one string that doesn't work.

It treats all characters the same, it's looking for an exact match.

Don't use filter() if you only want the first match. Use find().

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

If string is "Who has time for hobbies?" it won't match the icon name because it doesn't have spaces, it doesn't have ?, and it has uppercase characters where string is lowercase.

You need to write a canonicalization function that converts the search string to the icon format -- capitalize the words, remove punctuation and whitespace.

No, it doesn't. Punctuation is part of the string and is a string. You can utilize regex to make it work-


let iconNames=['SurfingIcon', 'SportsIcon', "WhoHasTimeForHobbiesIcon"]
string = "Who has time for hobbies"
let name = iconNames.filter(icon => icon.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/[^\w]/g, '')))[0];

console.log(name)



[^\w] is anything that's not a digit, letter.
